# how to enable tinymce custom buttons in meta box?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, wp-editor

I have a default setup for including external plugin for tinymce, that is working on default editor.

But not when tinymce used in metabox.

I there a way to force them to load there too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling wp_editor() in your metabox, one of the arguments that you can pass is 'media_buttons.'

Comment: That's for media upload, not what I need. I'm looking for a way to add custom buttons to tinymce editors, they even added already, but not appear on in the editor when it is in meta box